# mobile site not rendering

Tags: css, mobile, resize, smartphone

I have built a new template for my website that re-arranges the content so that the sidebar is moved to the bottom in the event a small screen size (<801px) is detected. In an effort to make this as simple as possible I have reduced it to html and CSS. The issue is the phones claim to have more screen size than they do and they choose the full size display anyway. Also if I specify the media type as "mobile", the phones seem to deliberately ignore it. Is there a better way to target the mobile phones (ie android and iPhone)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need the following `meta` tag in your `head`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```